# How to loop git status using scripting

Tags: git, scripting, git-status

I need a help with this:

I want to loop the git status code without status code or together status code in one line; I'm using the code below:

```
# file.sh
files=$(git status --porcelain)
for file in $files; do
    echo $file
done

# OUTPUT
M
example_folder/example_file
M
example_folder_1/example_file_1
M
example_folder_2/example_file_2
....
```

The problem is the status code always displays, I need to remove the status code or put it together like this:

```
# LINES EXPECTED
M example_folder/example_file
M example_folder_1/example_file_1
# OR
example_folder/example_file
example_folder_1/example_file_1
```

My objective is to output an input using console, like this:

```
files=$(git status --porcelain)
for file in $files; do
    echo $file
    git add $file
    read -p "enter a comment: " comments
    git commit -m "${comments}"
done
```

The code above is working, but the status code received the comment too, and I need to remove or put it in one line each line modified.

regards.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You want to write this:

```
#!/bin/sh

files=$(git status --porcelain | cut -b4-)
for file in $files; do
    echo $file
    git add $file
    read -p "enter a comment: " comments
    git commit -m "${comments}"
done
```

The `cut -b4-` trims off the status part of the output.

Answer (score 3):

`--porcelain` displays the result in [Short Format](https://git-scm.com/docs/git-status#_short_format).

> In the short-format, the status of each path is shown as one of these forms

```
XY PATH
XY ORIG_PATH -> PATH
```

The 2nd format occurs when `ORIG_PATH` is renamed to `PATH`. Use `awk` to get `PATH`.

```
files=$(git status --porcelain | awk '{print $NF}')
for file in $files; do
    echo $file
    git add $file
    read -p "enter a comment: " comments
    git commit -m "${comments}" -- ${file}
done
```